# Checking if a file or directory exists in Java

Tags: java, file, exists

From [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html) java tutorial by oracle:

> Note that !Files.exists(path) is not equivalent to
> Files.notExists(path).

Why would they not be equivalent? it does not go any further in terms of explanation.
Does anybody know more information about that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`!Files.exists()` returns:

- `true` if the file does not exist or its existence cannot be determined
- `false` if the file exists

`Files.notExists()` returns:

- `true` if the file does not exist
- `false` if the file exists or its existence cannot be determined

Answer (score 3):

As we see from [Files.exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) the return result is:

```
TRUE if the file exists; 
FALSE if the file does not exist or its existence cannot be determined.
```

And from [Files.notExists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#notExists%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) the return result is:

```
TRUE if the file does not exist; 
FALSE if the file exists or its existence cannot be determined
```

So if `!Files.exists(path)` return `TRUE` means it not exists or the existence cannot be determined (2 possibilities) and for `Files.notExists(path)` return `TRUE` means it not exists (just 1 possibility).

The conclusion `!Files.exists(path) != Files.notExists(path)` or `2 possibilities not equals to 1 possibility` (see the explanation above about the possibilities).

Answer (score 3):

Looking in the source code for the differences they both do the exact same thing with 1 major difference. The `notExist(...)` method has an extra exception to be caught.

Exist:

```
public static boolean exists(Path path, LinkOption... options) {
    try {
        if (followLinks(options)) {
            provider(path).checkAccess(path);
        } else {
            // attempt to read attributes without following links
            readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class,
                           LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
        }
        // file exists
        return true;
    } catch (IOException x) {
        // does not exist or unable to determine if file exists
        return false;
    }

}
```

Not Exist:

```
public static boolean notExists(Path path, LinkOption... options) {
    try {
        if (followLinks(options)) {
            provider(path).checkAccess(path);
        } else {
            // attempt to read attributes without following links
            readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class,
                           LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
        }
        // file exists
        return false;
    } catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
        // file confirmed not to exist
        return true;
    } catch (IOException x) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As a result the differences are as follow:

- `!exists(...)` returns the file as non existent if an `IOException` is thrown when attempting to retrieve the file.
- `notExists(...)` returns the file as non existent by making sure the specific `IOException` subexception `NoSuchFileFound` is thrown and that it isn't any other subexception on `IOException` causing the not found result

Comment: Hello is this serious, I am PHP dev and doing some project in Java. So there is no simple way to determine if folder exist and to be 100% sure. I am using JDK 6. I thought Java is mature language...

Answer (score 1):

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#notExists%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) of `notExists`.

> Note that this method is not the complement of the exists method. **Where it is not possible to determine if a file exists or not then both methods return false**. ...

My highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify the absolute path, if the directory/directories doesn't exits, it will create the drectory/directories.

```
private void createDirectoryIfNeeded(String directoryName)
{
File theDir = new File(directoryName); 
if (!theDir.exists())
    theDir.mkdirs();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 import java.io.File;

 // Create folder   
 boolean isCreate = new File("/path/to/folderName/").mkdirs();

 // check if exist 
 File dir = new File("/path/to/newFolder/");
 if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {

 //the folder exist..
 }
```

Can also check `if Boolean variable == True`, but this check is better and more effective.